# Can't Change Weight Paint to Anything but Blur

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

While trying to weight paint, I somehow got stuck with just the blur tool and I can't change it back to draw or any other brush type. What did I do and how do I restore this to normal?

[image: Weight paint mode with only blur available]

Comment: Hello what does it show if you press T (tool panel on the left)? Or maybe share your file (remove all the objects): https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select the right brush to get everything.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I needed to get the tool menu up again by pressing T. I don't know how I closed that menu, but that's why I couldn't find this. Thank you!